# Javascript: why does it show two new inputs even though I supplied only one new input?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm quite new to Javascript and I would appreciate any help.
My plan is to create a contact list. As someone supplies a new contact it should immediately show up in the table beneath it along with all of the other contacts with a surname beginning with the same letter. Unfortunately it seems to work fine only for the first 2 inputs. When I add a third contact it adds two more rows in the table when it should be only one more row. Another problem is the fact that when i click on the CANCEL button it doesn't work. Only on the second click it works and like the INSERT button after the second click it deletes 2 rows at a time.
Can anybody explain to me where the problem is? As I wrote before any help is appreciated. Thanks

```js
var contacts = [];

            function insert(){

                var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
                var surname = document.getElementById("surname").value;
                var number = document.getElementById("number").value;

                if ( !(/^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/.test(name)) || !(/^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/.test(surname)) || !(/^[0-9]*$/.test(number)) ){
                    alert("Something's wrong");
                    return;
                }

                var user = {
                    firstName : name,
                    lastName : surname,
                    telNumber : number
                };

                contacts.push(user);
                contacts.sort(compare);

                var letter = surname.toUpperCase().charAt(0);

                show(letter);
 
            }

            function compare( a, b ) {
                if ( a.lastName.toUpperCase() < b.lastName.toUpperCase() )
                        return -1;

                if ( a.lastName.toUpperCase() > b.lastName.toUpperCase() )
                    return 1;
                
                if ( a.firstName.toUpperCase() < b.firstName.toUpperCase() )
                    return -1;
                if ( a.firstName.toUpperCase() > b.firstName.toUpperCase() )
                    return 1;
        
                return 0;
            }

            function show(l){

                empty();

                var table = document.getElementById("table");

                for (var i=0; i<contacts.length; i++){

                    if (contacts[i].lastName.toUpperCase().charAt(0) == l){

                        var row = document.createElement('tr');

                        for (var j=0; j<3; j++){

                            var tile = document.createElement('td');
                            
                            switch(j){
                                case 0: tile.textContent = contacts[i].lastName; break;
                                case 1: tile.textContent = contacts[i].firstName; break;
                                case 2: tile.textContent = contacts[i].telNumber; 
                            }
                            row.appendChild(tile);
                        }
                        table.appendChild(row);
                    }
                }
            }

            function empty(){

                var rows = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');


                for (var i=1; i<rows.length; i++){

                    var tiles = rows[i].children;

                    for (var j=0; j<tiles.length; j++)
                        tiles[j].parentNode.removeChild(tiles[j]);
                    
                    rows[i].parentNode.removeChild(rows[i]);
                }

            }

function cancel(){

                var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
                var surname = document.getElementById("surname").value;

                if ( !(/^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/.test(name)) || !(/^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/.test(surname)) ) return;
                
                var index=0;
                while ( (contacts[index].lastName != surname) || (contacts[index].firstName != name) ) index++;

                contacts.splice(index,1);

                var letter = surname.toUpperCase().charAt(0);

                show(letter);
            }
```

```css
table{
                border-collapse: collapse;
                border: 1px black solid;
            }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="eng">
    <head>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Contacts List</title>
            </head>

    <body>
        <div id="left-container" class="container">

            <div id="insert-container" class="sub-container">
                <p>Surname</p><input type="text" name="surname" id="surname">
                <p>Name</p><input type="text" name="ame" id="name">
                <p>Telephone Number</p><input type="text" name="number" id="number"><br>

                <button onclick="insert()">INSERT</button><button onclick="cancel()">CANCEL</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="right-container" class="container">
            <table id="table">
                <tr><th>Surname</th><th>Name</th><th>Tel. Num.</th></tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: The example code you have provided doesn't reproduce the problem, it doesn't seem to work at all. Could you make it work like on your machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main problem. First is `empty` function that isn't work correctly. Because you made a loop through all `tr` and in loop you remove it! So after adding two rows you missed the first one to remove it. **It isn't good idea manipulate the length of the array that you made a loop over** it. (by removing you change the length of the rows)

I change  the `empty` method with simple one:

```
var mytbl = document.getElementById("table");
mytbl.innerHTML = mytbl.rows[0].innerHTML;
```

Another problem is that you never check length of `contacts` in `cancel` mehtods and if there is no more contact and still clicking on that some errors appears in console, so check the length of `contacts` and if it is empty return form the function:

```js
var contacts = [];

function insert() {
    debugger
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var surname = document.getElementById("surname").value;
    var number = document.getElementById("number").value;

    if (!(/^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/.test(name)) || !(/^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/.test(surname)) || !(/^[0-9]*$/.test(number))) {
        alert("Something's wrong");
        return;
    }

    var user = {
        firstName: name,
        lastName: surname,
        telNumber: number
    };

    contacts.push(user);
    contacts.sort(compare);

    var letter = surname.toUpperCase().charAt(0);

    show(letter);

}

function compare(a, b) {
    if (a.lastName.toUpperCase() < b.lastName.toUpperCase())
        return -1;

    if (a.lastName.toUpperCase() > b.lastName.toUpperCase())
        return 1;

    if (a.firstName.toUpperCase() < b.firstName.toUpperCase())
        return -1;
    if (a.firstName.toUpperCase() > b.firstName.toUpperCase())
        return 1;

    return 0;
}

function show(l) {
    empty();
    var table = document.getElementById("table");
    for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
        if (contacts[i].lastName.toUpperCase().charAt(0) == l) {
            var row = document.createElement('tr');
            for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                var tile = document.createElement('td');
                switch (j) {
                    case 0: tile.textContent = contacts[i].lastName; break;
                    case 1: tile.textContent = contacts[i].firstName; break;
                    case 2: tile.textContent = contacts[i].telNumber;
                }
                row.appendChild(tile);
            }
            table.appendChild(row);
        }
    }
}

function empty() {
    var mytbl = document.getElementById("table");
    mytbl.innerHTML = mytbl.rows[0].innerHTML;

}

function cancel() {
    if (contacts.length == 0)
        return;
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var surname = document.getElementById("surname").value;

    if (!(/^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/.test(name)) || !(/^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/.test(surname))) return;

    var index = 0;
    while ((contacts[index].lastName != surname) || (contacts[index].firstName != name)) index++;

    contacts.splice(index, 1);

    var letter = surname.toUpperCase().charAt(0);

    show(letter);
}
```

```html
<div id="left-container" class="container">
    <div id="insert-container" class="sub-container">
        <p>Surname</p><input type="text" name="surname" id="surname">
        <p>Name</p><input type="text" name="ame" id="name">
        <p>Telephone Number</p><input type="text" name="number" id="number"><br>

        <button onclick="insert()">INSERT</button><button onclick="cancel()">CANCEL</button>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="right-container" class="container">
    <table id="table">
        <tr><th>Surname</th><th>Name</th><th>Tel. Num.</th></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: You were right. Once I solved those 2 problems everything worked fine. Thank you!